# Why torch.FloatTensor([[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]],[[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]]) size is [2,2,3]?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

```
>>> ft = torch.FloatTensor([[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]],[[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]])
>>> print(ft.shape)
torch.Size([2, 2, 3])
```

I can't understand this result.
I think the torch size should be [2,3,2], but the result is [2,2,3].

Comment: Why do you think it should be something else?

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
len([[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]],[[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]]) = 2
```

This is the first 2.
and each item inside:

```
len([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]) = 2
```

This is the second 2.

and each item inside:

```
len([0,1,2]) = 3
```

This is the 3.

Comment: Oh, I thought that the size is [batch size, length, dim] but that wasn't. Thank you so much.